# ReactJs render simple JSON

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have simple json

```
{"id":157,"content":"Hello, World!"}
```

I want to render id in one div and content in anotther. Problem for me is when I call `{this.state.data.content}` twice it crash.

```
var Stuff = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            data: []
        };
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting",
          dataType: 'json',
          cache: false,
          success: function(response) {
            this.setState({
                data: response
            });
          }.bind(this),
          error: function(xhr, status, err) {
            console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
          }.bind(this)
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>Response - {this.state.data.content}</div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you [checked your console](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/hello-world/714/using-console-log) for errors?

Comment: I don't know what are you talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem solved by surrounding jsx with another div

```
 return (
     <div>
         <div>Response - {this.state.data.content}</div>
         <div>id - {this.state.data.id}</div>
      </div>
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, try to render a string instead of an object

```
render: function() {
   return (<div> Whatever - {JSON.stringify(this.state.data)}</div>)
}
```

Tipp:

if you want to make it pretty: use `JSON.stringify(this.state.data, null, 2)`